# First "should be_installed" in test always fails on Windows

Tags: windows, rspec, serverspec

First off, I'm using serverspec 2.3.1 and specinfra 2.4.2, with Ruby 1.9.3p550

I am still investigating the problem, but I figured I'd give a shot at asking here in case someone encountered the problem before (and if not and I figure it out, maybe the next person who does encounter it will find this answer on Google).

The goal is to have a spec file with all the softwares that should be installed on the test system. What is weird though is that no matter what I write, the first time I do `it { should be_installed }`, it will fail. No exception.

The code below shows what I mean:

```
require 'acceptance_helper'

describe package('7-Zip 9.22 (x64 edition)') do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe package('7-Zip 9.22 (x64 edition)') do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe package('Zend Server') do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe package('SQL Server 2012 Management Studio') do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe package('Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)') do
  it { should be_installed }
end
```

When I run this file, I'll get the first test that says 7-Zip is not installed and the second test will say it is. Anything I put as the first test does the same thing.

```
Package "7-Zip 9.22 (x64 edition)"
  should be installed (FAILED - 1)

Package "7-Zip 9.22 (x64 edition)"
  should be installed

Package "Zend Server"
  should be installed

Package "SQL Server 2012 Management Studio"
  should be installed

Package "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)"
  should be installed

Failures:

  1) Package "7-Zip 9.22 (x64 edition)" should be installed
     Failure/Error: it { should be_installed }
     TypeError:
       can't convert Symbol into Integer
       uname -s
       #< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Error">The term 'uname' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script fi_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">le, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inclu_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">ded, verify that the path is correct and try again._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:1 char:6_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ uname &lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;  -s_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (uname:String) [], CommandNotFou _x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">   ndException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>
 # ./spec/acceptance/192.168.0.70/all_required_applications_are_installed_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 25.96 seconds (files took 0.99763 seconds to load)
5 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/acceptance/192.168.0.70/all_required_applications_are_installed_spec.rb:4 # Package "7-Zip 9.22 (x64 edition)" should be installed
```

What's unreal to me is that only the first test will fail, so I'm really not sure what could be happening. I'll investigate and update this post as I go, but if anyone has ever encountered this, I'd really like to hear how/if you fixed this!

**Edit**: With the error message and the way ServerSpecs tests for packages on Windows, I thought the command was badly executed, but it turns out the error happens even before the command is run. At least it looks like it, since in Intellij IDEA, when I put a break point on line 7 of `specinfra/command/windows/base/package.rb` (`exec "(FindInstalledApplication -appName '#{package}' #{version_selection}) -eq $true"`), the break point is never reached, the test fails and it goes to the next test.

**Edit 2**: Managed to isolate the problem a bit more, it seems to happen in `specinfra\helper\os.rb`. I'm new to Ruby, so it's a bit hard to debug, but I'm guessing something isn't initialized properly on the first run of whatever ServerSpec/SpecInfra uses to detect OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turns out I'm silly and can't read documentation properly. They say on Serverspec's documentation that Windows OS need to be specified in the spec_helper and I had only copy/pasted the example helper from their [Windows doc](https://github.com/serverspec/serverspec/blob/master/WINDOWS_SUPPORT.md).

This is my helper file now, notice the `set :os` line

```
require 'serverspec'
require 'winrm'
require 'yaml'

set :backend, :winrm
set :os, :family => 'windows', :release => '2008', :arch => 'x64'

base_path = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
config = YAML.load_file(File.join(base_path, 'config.yml'))

user = 'vagrant'
pass = 'vagrant'
endpoint = "http://#{config['host_ip']}:5985/wsman"

winrm = ::WinRM::WinRMWebService.new(endpoint, :ssl, :user => user, :pass => pass, :basic_auth_only => true)
winrm.set_timeout 300 # 5 minutes max timeout for any operation
Specinfra.configuration.winrm = winrm
```

Comment: I was seeing a similar issue with file-related tests, where it would intermittently fail with a message that `uname` couldn't be found. Setting the OS and family explicitly in spec_helper.rb seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks for posting that. I'll see if I can open a PR for them to update the documentation.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!! Thanks for the PR (I should have done that, I don't know why I didn't think about it), I'm sure it'll help a lot of people!